# Is there a way to delay the execution of the completable future?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-stream, completable-future

I'll be using CompletableFuture for my async calls. I would like to know if there's a way to delay its execution. I have around 5 async calls for one flow, and I am chaining then using thenApply/thenCompose as required. My problem is when I create the first CF for a call, it'll start executing whenever a thread is free. I want that first all my tasks should be chained, then when I call , say complete(), it starts executing. What I am looking for is something similar to the intermediate operations in Java streams. I had some help regarding this in one of my earlier questions on SO, but it's not solving my purpose.

My tech stack only allows Java 8, so can't use any features launched in the next versions.

Comment: Why do you need a delay?

Comment: That's the kind of functionality I want to provide. User can chain multiple operations on my domain object (similar to fluent interfaces), and actual computation should start when he clicks execute. Also my custom flow requires 5 different calls, which are dependent. To me, it doesn't seem right that I am still building a flow, and it already starts executing in the background.

Comment: So keep the pieces in a list and compose them when you're ready...

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely an option. I'll try it right away. However, I'd also like to know if there's a way to do it along the lines of java streams, considering they're designed around stateless intermediate operations

Edit: Actually, I can't just keep a list of suppliers with the logic, I need separate error handling for each CF, so I need to build a CF with the core and exception logic. So I have to maintain another list of error Function, which imo isn't the most readable and maintainable approach

Comment: I still don't really get the problem with immediate execution. Adding a chained call doesn't affect previous computations, so what's the difference when each stage runs?

Comment: It's not comparable to streams from a technical perspective, because with streams, each element (generally) is processed independently, so you need the full pipeline in place before you can start iterating. But with one element there's not much difference. That's why `Optional` doesn't use lazy evaluation.

Comment: I'll try to explain in detail. So, I have 5 calls (A,B,C,D,E), and each of these calls is reusable for some any flow. I plan to define the CF for these calls in a utility class, with methods like getA(), getB() and based on my flow, I'll reuse them. The problem is, when I do getA(), it'll start executing the call, and I am yet to chain it to other calls for my flow. That, is not the right way imo, since the flow is not completely defined yet. I'd just like to have the control when the CF begins execution, and that should be, after I complete the chaining logic. Does it make sense?

Comment: do not use CompletableFuture at all. Just start a thread, which will do all the computations, and will call to Thread.sleep() whenever a delay is needed.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why a delay should be needed. For the flow defined by `CompletableFuture`, the time of execution is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't write comments yet, so I cannot ask for clarification. Please forgive me, if I didn't understand correctly, what you need. From what I can tell, you're basically just looking for a way to delay the execution of a CompletableFuture until you are ready to do so.

Have you considered giving another CF as parameter to the function you want to call? Once you are ready, just complete this CF and then the function gets executed. 
It goes somewhat like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> setup = new CompletableFuture<>();
delayedFunction(setup);

//do whatever you want
System.out.println("foo");

//once you are ready, complete setup to execute the delayed function
setup.complete(null);


public static CompletableFuture<Void> delayedFunction(CompletableFuture<Void> setup) {
  return setup.
    thenAccept(v-> {
      System.out.println("bar");
    });
}
```

Comment: This solves my purpose. Funny, how I ignored the most basic constructor while reading about CF and focussed on the chaining methods. Thanks Tobias!